# Match a pattern having tilde in Python using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract content from a pattern like this `~~o3i320-4fjkhe~~` in Python using regular expression.

I have tried the following:

```
pattern1 = r'\~\~(.*?)\~\~'
pattern2 = r'~~(.*?)~~'
m = re.search(pattern2, text)

print(m.group()[2:-2])
```

Neither `pattern1` nor `pattern2` works. I am new to regular expressions and am struggling with this. Not quite sure what I am missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Have you defined `text = '~~o3i320-4fjkhe~~'`? Just add this line and it will work fine and tilde is no special character in regex, so don't need to escape it.

Comment: There is *nothing special* about `~` in a regular expression. Replace '~' with 'X' in the pattern and input: the behavior will be the same.

Comment: I would question using `m.group()[2:-2]` to 'prove' that it "doesn't match"; if `m` is not-None then there *was* a match, even if the capture group does not exist as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the matches incorrectly.  You want to access the first capture group:

```
text = "~~o3i320-4fjkhe~~"
pattern = r'\~\~(.*?)\~\~'
m = re.search(pattern, text)

print(m.group(1))
print(m.group(1)[2:-2])

o3i320-4fjkhe
i320-4fjk
```

Update: If you really wanted to work with the full match, we could try using lookarounds in the pattern instead:

```
text = "~~o3i320-4fjkhe~~"
pattern = r'(?<=~~)(.*)(?=~~)'
m = re.search(pattern, text)
print(m.group())

o3i320-4fjkhe
```

Comment: Everything works fine if he declares `text` variable. He is doing `m.group()` which will give full match and then out of that he is excluding 2 characters from both the sides which will give him the output as needed but instead he could easily do `m.group(1)` And `~` doesn't need escaping as it is simple plain character in regex.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I should have asked what "not works" means to the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Wow! This works for me, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yes, the only and only mistake I can see in OPs code is, he didn't declare the `text` variable otherwise everything works perfect and outputs the string which OP seems to targeting seeing his `m.group()[2:-2]` expression.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi: Actually, with the code I posted, I got "IndexError: no such group".

Comment: @Gingerbread: You shouldn't have gotten any such error because you weren't accessing any indexed group. `m.group()` this will give you the full matching text but if you access something like `m.group(1)` or `m.group(2)` and if you don't have any parenthesis in your regex, then yes you will surely get that error you told.